# Handling back click after launching the Android default web browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, browser, uri

From my Android app I wish to launch the default web browser to send the user to a verification web page, and then once verified use a callback to send them back to my app.

I have that functionality working ok, but what I'm having difficulty with is intercepting the situation where the user decides they don't want to verify themselves in the web browser and clicks the back button to return to my app.

I've tried launching the web browser with startActivityForResult() so I can intercept back clicks using onActivityResult(), but for some reason onActivityResult() is called immediately after launching the web browser, and not at all when the user clicks back.

Here's some basic test code that demonstrates the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("MainActivity","onCreate called");

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);

        startActivityForResult(intent,101);

        Log.i("MainActivity","startActivityForResult called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        Log.i("MainActivity","onResume called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.i("MainActivity","onActivityResult called");
    }
}
```

Output after running this code:

```
I/MainActivity(545): onCreate called
I/MainActivity(545): startActivityForResult called
I/MainActivity(545): onResume called
I/MainActivity(545): onActivityResult called
I/MainActivity(545): onResume called
```

Then if the user clicks back from the web browser, it just calls onResume() a third time.

So given that, would anyone have any suggestion on how I can recognise when the user clicked back from the browser?

Comment: Hey I'm trying to add the functionality to close the browser when authentication/payment is done!
can you help with that ?
could you tell me what was your solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about giving this a try:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Comment: Hiya, that was useful idea and it seems to be working ok with a bit of quick hackery. Thanks for that! and if anyone else lands up here I also found that another option would be to wrap a WebView with an activity, rather than launch the Android web browser, then you have more control over the user browsing inputs.

Comment: @Givi I found it useless, since it act on each dialogue and any window focus change, so may you know why this happen and what is global control for this case? This is my code : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/990063/Why-onActivityResult-can-not-catch-result-from-bro?arn=1

Answer (score 0):

the reason for your logs is :

1. You called  `startActivityForResult(intent,101);` from `onCreate()`. `onResume()` lifecycle method conventionally is followed by `onCreate()`, thats why you see the first `onResume()`
2. the browser always opens in a new task, so `onActivityResult()` will be called immediately, with resultCode `RESULT_CANCELLED`
3. on coming back, your activity is visible again, and you will see `onResume()` in your log